# Can't get git to ignore App_Data mdf file in VS

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitignore

I have an App_Data folder in my Visual Studio web project.
I have commmitted a *.mdf to the repository and referenced it in web.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="foo" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\foo.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connection Timeout=30" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

When I do a fresh pull from the repository, my project starts and mounts the database.

I do not want to modify this database as part of check-ins.

However, if the database is modified by debugging the app, the *.mdf file appears as a "Change".
I added **/App_Data to .gitignore, but it still keeps seeing those files.

I thought it might be a lock problem, but I verifid this happens when there are no locks on files.

If I add a txt file to the folder git ignores it.

Any ideas ???

Comment: it sounds like your *.mdf is already tracked. The ignore file won't affect files you've explicitly added to the repo. What you're probably looking for is assume-unchanged.

Comment: what is assume-unchanged ?

Comment: It's an index command, it allows you to tell git that you're going to change a file git is already tracking, but you don't want to commit those changes. [git update-index](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#git-update-index---no-assume-unchanged)

Comment: I can block the check-in with assume-unchanged...but how can I make sure other developers do not check in changes ? There does not seem to be anything committed to the repository I can use like gitignore. I guess I am looking for something like tfs's "Cloak"